# TinyMCE bug with block elements

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce, website-admin-tool, website-admin

I have a problem with TinyMCE:

I need to get this code:

```
<blockquote>
    <h2>REVOLUTIONARY QUOTE RELATING MANIFESTO TO PROJECT GOES HERE</h2>
    <hr/>
    <p>Erik Heinsholt</p>
</blockquote>
```

TinyMCE settings:

```
valid_elements: "a[href|target|title],ul,ol,li,br,strong/b,em/i,span[style<text-decoration: underline;|class],u,p,blockquote,hr,h2",
force_br_newlines: false,
force_p_newlines: true,
theme_advanced_buttons1: "undo,redo,|,bold,italic,underline,|,hr,code,preview, styleselect",
schema: "html5",
style_formats : [
    {title : "First Word", inline : "span", classes : "first_word"},
    {title : "Blockquote", block : "blockquote"},
    {title : "Quote Header", inline : "h2"}
]
```

What I have: I write in admin textarea "REVOLUTIONARY QUOTE RELATING MANIFESTO TO PROJECT GOES HERE `<hr />` Erik Heisholt", then select "REVOLUTIONARY QUOTE RELATING MANIFESTO TO PROJECT GOES HERE", set a style "Quote Header" for it, then select all and set a style "Blockquote" for it. As a result I get this:

```
<blockquote><h2>REVOLUTIONARY QUOTE RELATING MANIFESTO TO PROJECT GOES HERE</h2></blockquote>
<blockquote><hr /></blockquote>
<blockquote><p>Erik Heinsholt</p></blockquote>
```

What should I do to put all elements in one blockquote tag, not each element??

p.s.: the video describing this problem: http://www.sendspace.com/file/nkz97d

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tinymce configuration parameters [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children).
You can define that `h2`- and `hr`-tags may be childs to other htmlnodes.

Comment: I put this        valid_children: "+blockquote[h2], +blockquote[hr]",
and then this     valid_children: "+blockquote[h2,hr]",
but it still doesn't work correctly.
Maybe the syntax is wrong?

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle with this?

Comment: sry, i won't donwnload ilivid

Comment: you clicked wrong button with ads. Please click here to download: "Click here to start download from sendspace".

Comment: got it now. i am sorry, but i do not know how to solve this. you may still ask in the tinymce forum